# PHP Parameterized PostgreSQL Query with pg_execute or pg_query_params Functions Returns null, But pg_exec Working Fine

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am facing an issue while executing parameterized queries to get data from PostgreSQL database using PHP.

```
//Function Code: DBHRSQ
    //$query = "SELECT * FROM grievance_by WHERE status = 1"
    //$valuesArr = null
    private function runSelectQuery($query,$valuesArr,$datatypes = null){

        $pstmt = pg_prepare($this->conn, "select_query", $query);
        $pstmt = pg_execute($this->conn, "select_query", $valuesArr); //Getting null here

        //$pstmt = pg_exec($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM grievance_by WHERE status = 1"); <--THIS ONE IS WORKING

        if(pg_result_error($pstmt)){
            $this->closeConn();
            return $this->setAndReturnResponse(500,
            "DBHRSQM: Operation failed. Error occured while fetching the data.",
            "DBHRSQD: Error while execution of query: $query", false);
        }

        $rows = pg_fetch_all($pstmt,PGSQL_ASSOC);

        pg_free_result($pstmt);
        $this->closeConn();

        return $this->setAndReturnResponse(200, "DBHRSQM: Success", 
        "DBHRSQD: Select operation completed successfully", true, $rows);
    }
```

If I execute the same query in using `pg_exec()` I am getting expected data from the DB. Facing issue only when I use `pg_prepare() + pg_execute()` or `pg_query_params().`

> PostgreSQL Version : 14

> PHP Version: 7.3.9 (Bundled with XAMPP)

> OS: Windows 10

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: What parameterised query? `SELECT * FROM tablename` is not parameterised

Comment: Unless your $valuesArr is empty, this of course can't work - your query does not contain any placeholders to substitute with values from that array.

Comment: Start with pg_query_params() for queries with parameters, but you don't have queries like that.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I tried pg_query_params() but it is also not working.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated my question for more clarity.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the actual query is in parameter. I initialized again inside function just for the clarification. I edited my question with actual code.

Comment: Could it be the driver issue? php_pgsql.dll or php_pdo_pgsql.dll?

Comment: @RiggsFolly So I cannot execute simple query like `SELECT * FROM tablename` using pg_prepare() + pg_execute() ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is `pg_prepare() + pg_execute()` only works when query contains any parameter for eg: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field1 = $1` but whenever the query is simple for eg: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE status = 1` which does not contain any dynamic parameter `pg_execute()` returns null.

So I fixed this issue by adding a condition in function itself and now my function looks like this:

```
private function runSelectQuery($query,$valuesArr,$datatypes = null){
    /** Use pg_prepare only when array $valuesArr is not null **/
    if($valuesArr){
        $pstmt = pg_prepare($this->conn, "select_query", $query);
        $pstmt = pg_execute($this->conn, "select_query", $valuesArr);
    }
    /** Else execute as a plain query **/
    else{
        $pstmt = pg_exec($this->conn, $query);
    }
    if(pg_result_error($pstmt)){
        $this->closeConn();
        return $this->setAndReturnResponse(500,
        "DBHRSQM: Operation failed. Error occured while fetching the data.",
        "DBHRSQD: Error while execution of query: $query", false);
    }
    $rows = pg_fetch_all($pstmt,PGSQL_ASSOC);
    pg_free_result($pstmt);
    $this->closeConn();
    return $this->setAndReturnResponse(200, "DBHRSQM: Success", 
    "DBHRSQD: Select operation completed successfully", true, $rows);
}
```

Now it is working!